# SQLRPGLE syntax for Exec sql from a varying length variable?

Tags: sql, db2-400, rpgle

On IBMi (database is DB2 for i) in SQLRPGLE I have a program that builds a large SQL statement into a variable that I would like to run.

When I try to run it as a variable I receive a token error

Some background

Here is an example that works because it does not use a variable

```
Exec SQL                                                                
Create table MyLib/MyFile as(select * from XXLIB/XXFILE)   
DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED                       
maintained by user;
```

When I save this in a variable like @SQLStm and then try to execute as SQL

```
Exec SQL                  
   :@SQLStm;
```

I get the error 
Token : was not valid. Valid tokens: .

Also I am open to different approaches
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/runsqlstm.htm
Like RUNSQLSTM   SRCFILE(MYLIB/MYFILE)  SRCMBR(MYMBR)

Maybe there is a way to take a variable and save it to a source member?
Then use RUNSQLSTM over the source member

Showing some code:
Definition for the variable

```
d @SQLStm         s               A   Len(6144) Varying(4)
```

Even when trying a portion of the SQL statement as a variable

```
@SQLStm = select * from XXLIB/XXFILE;
```

and then try:

```
Exec SQL     
  Create table MyLib/MyFile as( :@SQLStm)    
  DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED                       
  maintained by user;
```

I get the error 
Token : was not valid. Valid tokens: .

I expect the SQLRPLE to compile
Instead of SQL precompile failed.

MSG ID  SEV  RECORD  TEXT
SQL0104  30     236  Position 31 Token : was not valid. Valid tokens:
                     .

Message Summary
  Total     Info   Warning      Error   Severe  Terminal
      1        0         0          0        1         0
30 level severity errors found in source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is static SQL

```
Exec SQL                                                                
Create table MyLib/MyFile as(select * from XXLIB/XXFILE)   
DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED                       
maintained by user;
```

What you want is dynamic SQL

```
wSqlStmt = 'Create table MyLib/MyFile as(select * from XXLIB/XXFILE)'
            + ' DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED'
            + ' maintained by user'; 
exec SQL
  execute immediate :wSqlStmt;
```

Note that some statements can't be `execute immediate`  instead you have to `prepare` then `execute` them.

more information can be found in the [Embedded SQL programming](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajp/rzajpkickoff.htm) manual.

Comment: Thanks!  how would you do the same thing with a prepare?

Comment: nevermind I found the syntax
    `Exec SQL PREPARE S1 FROM :@SQLStm; `         
                                            
    `Exec SQL                                    
         EXECUTE S1;`

Comment: @VAIJason correct...note that while _every_ example shows names like S1, C1 ect...you should use a long _unique_ name.  Otherwise, you'll run into conflicts in production...when you have programs with SQL calling other programs with SQL.